# How to make @string in Android xml appear as a normal text?

Tags: android, xml

As the title says, How to make @string in Android xml appear as a normal text?

For example:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I want the output to be:

`@string/app_name`

not:

`MyApp`

I know I can set the text at runtime or make a string resource with the value `@string/app_name`.

My question is if there is a possibility to hard code it this way?

Comment: set text at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the `@` character:

`android:text="\@string/app_name"`

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

Escape the `@` in the `TextView`:

```
android:text="\@string/app_name"
```

But you will get a hard coded string warning.

Option 2:

Escape the `@` at `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="app_name_with_at_string">\@string/app_name</string>
```

Comment: you shouldn't change the `app_name` instead make a different string value

Comment: Then it's the first option that you need.